# Disable unused-const-variable build error in Android Studio (Gradle build)

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0, clang++

I'm debugging an Android native C++ code and I have a few variables and functions that I'm using for debug purpose and I would like to keep them in my code.

Problem is everytime I try to make my code Build fails with following error

```
***\android-sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe 
    [[REMOVED FOR CLARITY]]
    -Werror=format-security
    -std=gnu++11
    -Wall
    -Werror
    -O0
    -fno-limit-debug-info
    -fPIC -MD -MT CMakeFiles/native-activity.dir/main.cpp.o
    -MF CMakeFiles\native-activity.dir\main.cpp.o.d
    -o CMakeFiles/native-activity.dir/main.cpp.o
    -c ***/app/src/main/cpp/main.cpp
***/app/src/main/cpp/main.cpp:48:19: error: unused variable 'VERTEX_SHADER' [-Werror,-Wunused-const-variable]
    static const char VERTEX_SHADER[] =
                      ^
1 errors generated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Which suggests that If I want to disable this error I need to disable flag `unused-const-variable`

so I modified my gradle build file as such

```
defaultConfig {
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            cppFlags '-Wno-unused-const-variable','-Wno-unused-variable'
            arguments '-DANDROID_STL=c++_static'
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I try to Build my project I see the same error except `cppFlags` are added to command line parameters with no effect.

```
***\android-sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe
    [[REMOVED FOR CLARITY]]
    -Werror=format-security
    -Wno-unused-const-variable
    -Wno-unused-variable
    -std=gnu++11
    -Wall
    -Werror
    -O0
    -fno-limit-debug-info
    -fPIC -MD -MT CMakeFiles/native-activity.dir/main.cpp.o
    -MF CMakeFiles\native-activity.dir\main.cpp.o.d
    -o CMakeFiles/native-activity.dir/main.cpp.o
    -c ***/Projects/AndroidNDK/app/src/main/cpp/main.cpp
***/app/src/main/cpp/main.cpp:48:19: error: unused variable 'VERTEX_SHADER' [-Werror,-Wunused-const-variable]
static const char VERTEX_SHADER[] =
                  ^
1 errors generated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I even tried to disable Unused code from Android Studio  -> Editor -> inespection -> C++ -> Unused Code, which also has no effect.

**Question**

How do I disable build fail on warning or if not possible disable this error?

**Note:**

I'm working with android studio 3.4.1 on a Gradle build NDK native C++ code project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem myself. [GCC Warning Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) specifies that:

> -Werror: Make all warnings into errors.
>
> -Wall:   This enables all the warnings about constructions that some users consider questionable

These were not set on gradle build level, instead they were included in `CMakeLists.txt` file in following line

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11 -Wall -Werror")
```

Simply removing the last two option was enough to make both me and cmake happy.
Now I need to modify my MAKE file to include those parameters back for release build and remove them for debug build.